# Как передать переменную в функцию при помощи сигнал-слота?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Начал изучать *Qt* и в качестве закрепления информации решил создать проект, в котором вектор пушБаттонов будет посылать сигнал в функцию, функция в свою очередь производит вычисления, сохраняет в *SQLite* базу и выводит на соответствующий ЛайнЕдит (тоже вектор). Однако, на этапе объединения, кнопки и функции, я столкнулся с трудностями так как не знаю, как это можно правильно организовать.

Моя изначальная идея была в том, чтобы создать цикл, который бы объединял баттоны с функцией и передавал значения `i`, для определения с какой именно кнопки поступил сигнал, что вроде этого:

```
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    QObject::connect(button[i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, MainWindow::function);
}
```

Однако, я не нашел способа передать значение `i` в функцию. Слышал про `QSingalMapper` и использования лямбды, но из-за недостатка опыта так и не разобрался как это можно реализовать.

Буду признателен, если продемонстрируете, как в таком случае можно перекинуть `i` внутрь функции. Или, если моя идея неверна в принципе, предложите другой вариант ее реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С использованием лямбда-функций всё намного проще:

```
connect(button[i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=] () { function(i); });
```

В зависимости от того какие переменные необходимо захватить в контекст лямбда-функции, слот может выглядеть по-другому:

```
connect(button[i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, i] () { function(i); });
```

Такой функционал доступен, начиная с `C++11`.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Эту задачу решает [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html)

```
signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
{
    //создали кнопку
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(texts[i]);
    //привязали к мэпперу
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
    //указали, что кнопка мэппится в int
    signalMapper->setMapping(button, i);

}
//связываем сигнал из мэппера со слотом
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)),
        this, SIGNAL(clicked(int)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Так же, как альтернатива, можно использовать `property`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++) {
    button[i]->setProperty("index", i);
    QObject::connect(button[i], &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::function);
}
```

а в `function`:

```
QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender());
int index = button->property("index");
```